# Selecting time intervals of value live - missing first and last intervals

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a table with following structure

**| ChangedDate | IDParameter | ChangedTo(bit column) |**

So I need to get time intervals when my parameter is True or False, like following

**| IDParameter | ChangedToDate1 | ChangedToDate2 | ChangedTo(true to false || false to true)**

and I do

```
With RankedDates As
(
    Select T1.[ChangedDate], T1.ID, T1.[ChangedToValue]
    , Row_Number() Over( Partition By T1.ID Order By T1.[ChangedDate] ) As Num
    From [Changes] As T1
 )

  SELECT T1.[ID]
      ,T2.[ChangedToValue]
      ,T1.[ChangedDate] AS startDate
      ,T2.[ChangedDate] AS endDate
  FROM [RankedDates] AS T1
    Join RankedDates As T2
                    On T2.ID = T1.ID
                          And T2.Num = T1.Num + 1
                          And T2.[ChangedToValue] <> T1.[ChangedToValue]
                    Order By T2.[ChangedDate]
```

**The trouble is that I am missing first and last intervals here. it must be NULL for start date if that is first and NULL for endDate for last interval for each Parameter ID.** I guess I need add it with UNION but my trouble I can't understand how to add it for each IDParameter.

I don't know when value were changed first time and I don't know if the value will be changed in any time so I need NULL or some mindate for first intervals and NULL or some maxdate for last intervals.

ms sql server 2008

sorry for such complex question.

**Example :**

```
08.03.2011 ID1 0 -> 1 
09.03.2011 ID1 1 -> 0
09.03.2011 ID2 0 -> 1 
10.03.2011 ID1 0 -> 1 
10.03.2011 ID2 1 -> 0
```

**--->**

```
NULL , 08.03.2011 ID1 is 0
NULL , 09.03.2011 ID2 is 0
08.03.2011, 09.03.2011 ID1 is 1
09.03.2011, 10.03.2011 ID2 is 1
09.03.2011, 10.03.2011 ID1 is 0
10.03.2011, NULL ID1 is 1
10.03.2011, NULL ID2 is 0
```

Comment: I like the fact that you're saying sorry for the complex programming question... complexity is something most geeks love :)

Comment: Also complex questions are the primary reason why we need and have such sites as SO, even though people now come here with basic knowledge questions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using `FULL JOIN` instead of `JOIN`?

Does it solve your problem?

**EDIT:**

I think this should work as you want.

```
select  isnull(T1.ID, T2.ID) as ID
        ,isnull(T2.[ChangedToValue], case when T1.[ChangedToValue] = 1 then 0 else 1 end) as [ChangedToValue]
        ,T1.[ChangedDate] as startdate
        ,T2.[ChangedDate] as enddate
from    [RankedDates] T1
full join [RankedDates] T2
    on T2.num = T1.num +1
    and T2.ID = T1.ID
    and T1.[ChangedToValue] <> T2.[ChangedToValue]

order by 
    case when T2.[ChangedDate] is null then 1 else 0 end
    ,T2.[ChangedDate]
```

You where right about the `ChangedToValue`, I modified it to show the opposite now, if T2 is null.

Comment: not ... I think I need to emulate them I don't know when value were changed first time and I don't know if the value will be changed in any time so I need NULL or some mindate for first intervals and NULL or some maxdate for last intervals.

Comment: Ok then, can you provide some sample data?

Comment: isnull(T2.[ChangedToValue], T1.[ChangedToValue]) as [ChangedToValue] is T1 or T2 ? .....

Comment: isnull(x, y) works as: if x is null then use y instead.
Since we have a join on ID this should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming thats how your base table looks:
ChangeDate      IDParameter     ChangedTo
2011-03-08  ID1         True
2011-03-09  ID1         False
2011-03-09  ID2         True
2011-03-10  ID1         True
2011-03-10  ID2         False

```
SELECT  (SELECT TOP 1 t0.[ChangeDate] FROM [calendardb].[dbo].[Table_1] t0 
WHERE t0.IDParameter = t1.IDParameter AND t0.ChangeDate < t1.ChangeDate ORDER 
BY t0.ChangeDate DESC),
   [ChangeDate]
  ,[IDParameter]
  ,[ChangedTo]
FROM [calendardb].[dbo].[Table_1] t1
UNION 
SELECT MAX(ChangeDate) as maxd ,NULL,[IDParameter],
(SELECT ChangedTo FROM [calendardb].[dbo].[Table_1] t0 WHERE t0.ChangeDate =    (SELECT MAX(ChangeDate) FROM [calendardb].[dbo].[Table_1]
GROUP BY [IDParameter] HAVING IDParameter = t1.IDParameter) AND t1.IDParameter = t0.IDParameter)

FROM [calendardb].[dbo].[Table_1] t1
GROUP BY [IDParameter]
```

will give you result like this:

NULL    2011-03-08  ID1         1
2011-03-08  2011-03-09  ID1         0
NULL    2011-03-09  ID2         1
2011-03-09  2011-03-10  ID1         1
2011-03-09  2011-03-10  ID2         0
2011-03-10  NULL    ID1         1
2011-03-10  NULL    ID2         0

Comment: can't understand how your query works... why order with "select top 1" , and where "NULL" comes from ?

Comment: i just want to select the last record before the current that's why i use top 1 (need only the previous one) before current ( where date < date ) and it must the oldest one of all previous ( orderby date desc). If there is no prev, subquery will return NULL

Comment: Oh, I see. but what about last intervals when second date is NULL then ? must I add them manually with UNION ?

Comment: oh forgot about that, this part is complicated :)

Comment: Yes , it's looking like fine. But now I can't chose between you and Johan's solutions.